# Compare folders with DateTime Stamps - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a directory (Say **Main** folder) which contains two sub-directories. The two sub-directories have date-time stamp in their names: Like **folder07242020_15_21PM** and **folder07242020_15_26PM**. The Date and Time stamp in their names represent the date-time when they were created.

Can someone help me write a python code which will go to the **Main** folder, read the sub-directory names and then print something like

"folder07242020_15_26PM was created after folder07242020_15_21PM".

Thanks.

Comment: You can use e.g. `datetime.datetime.strptime("folder07242020_15_26PM", "folder%m%d%Y_%H_%M%p")` to parse the filenames into `datetime` objects and then compare them using ordinary comparison operators.

Comment: To read the subdirectory names, just use `os.listdir("Main")`. You could do for example `[name for name in os.listdir("Main") if name.startswith("folder")]` in order to ignore anything not of relevance.

Comment: If they are not literally called "folder" in the names, then you will probably have to use regexp to extract the timestamp part, e.g. `\d{8}_\d{2}_\d{2}(AM|PM)` - you could make a list of 2-tuples containing extracted timestamps (converted to datetime objects using `strptime` as above) and the full filenames. Then sort that list.